# Simple acceleration and velocity conceptual problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A tram moved from rest with constant acceleration, and after $10$s has travelled $400m$ forward.

a) Determine the tram's acceleration in $m/s^2$

Okay first I use $v = \frac{s}{t}$ which is $v = \frac{400}{10} = 40m/s$ and then I followed this up with $a = \frac{v-u}{t}$ which is $a = \frac{40 - 0}{10} = 4m/s^2$

Now checked the answer and it is incorrect, so i used another kinematics formula instead.

$s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2$

And this time I get

$400 = 0  + \frac{1}{2} \times a \times 100$

solving for $a$ gives $ a= 8m/s^2$

Can someone please explain why they produce different answer and why is the second method is the correct one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tram is moving at constant acceleration, it cannot be moving at constant velocity. Therefore you can't use $v=s/t$. That only provides the average velocity, not $v(t)$ (here this notation means the velocity as a function of time).

The second kinematics equation works for constant acceleration, hence it's the correct equation to use.

Comment: $v = \frac{s}{t}$ only calculates average velocity? So when exactly can I use the kinematics equation? I am guessing only for constant acceleration and linear motion? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Also if the question says something like "accelerating at 4m/s^2$, this is constant acceleration right? How can I identify constant acceleration and non-constant acceleration in a question?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk $v=s/t$ only calculates average velocity, yes. You use it when your velocity is constant. You can tell something is constant if it doesn't change throughout the question, which as you write in the OP, "A tram moved from rest with *constant acceleration*", so it's given as an assumption.

Comment: Right thanks for the reply. Another question says "accelerating at $4m/s^2$", is this constant or not? I assume it is constant, since $4m/s^2$ is a constant value

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk yeah, that would be constant acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have very deep misunderstanding regarding kinematics. The thing you did at first is wrong, because the formula $v = s/t$ only applies if the velocity was uniform. You need to understand that the train was accelerating $all$ $along$ it's motion. So it's velocity was never $40m/s$ until the very last instant when it stopped. So you have to use the other formula which takes into account this gradual change in velocity (which implies the train travels different distances at different instants of time).

Answer (score 0):

In your first calculation, you found the average velocity.  To find the acceleration you need the final velocity.